# Xml serialization and different languages (internationalization)

Tags: c#, xml, serialization, internationalization

What is a good solution to do XML serialization in different languages (internationalization) so that tags and attributes are serialized to the same object with different language?

I save configuration in xml and want to support german and english for the xml.

I don't really know how a good approach for this issue looks like.

Best solution would be but doesn´t exist:

```
[XmlRoot("MyEnglishConfig,MeineDeuscheKonfiguration")]
public class Test
{
    [XmlElement(ElementName="Setting1,Einstellung1")]
    public String value1;
}
```

so that both xml versions are parsed correct:

```
<MyEnglishConfig>
    <Setting1>English value</Setting1>
<MyEnglishConfig>

<MeineDeuscheKonfiguration>
    <Einstellung1>deutscher Wert</Einstellung1>
</MeineDeuscheKonfiguration>
```

Comment: [*What have you tried?*](http://whathaveyoutried.com)

Comment: XML serializer is ment to be culture invariant. Have you tried parsing german and seeing what happens?

Comment: Are you saying you want the tags and attributes to be in potentially one of 2 languages ie <Age Value="10"/> can be <Alter Wert="10"> say (ignore my german grammar here!)?  Do you plan / need to allow mixing of languages, ie sections in german within an otherwise  english document?

Comment: I think you don't understand my problem Yuval. I updated the question. Tolanj did understand.

Comment: One option is you view (say) English as the Master and have the translation done via a Xsl / LinqToXml / whatever done post / pre (de serialization).  Ie you allow the .Net setup to be in a single language and place a wrapper around where you save / load that config.
Is this a viable appoach for you?  If so what are the difficulties with it?
Arhh any of 'Fields' complex, ie you are relying on embedded complex types?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> What is a good solution to do XML serialization in different languages (internationalization) so that tags and attributes are serialized to the same object with different language?

Don't! That simply isn't a good thing to do, and virtually no libraries will help you do it. By all means localize and internationalize a maintenance UI; but leave the xml in a single culture. This is just asking for extreme pain. The type of people who are going to be manually editing an xml file *probably aren't going to mind* if they need to read tags in a different language.

If you *needed* to do that, [`XmlAttributeOverrides`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.serialization.xmlattributeoverrides%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) can be used to make a per-language serializer, but... yeuch.